# In Zend framework getting 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: php, pdo, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

I have one issue in zend framework got stuck due to this error

I developed Rest API but POST urls not working

```
500: Internal Server Error
```

but all get urls are working

When i debug all code its showing me error in AbstractTableGateway.php at line no 290 in executeInsert function

```
$result = $statement->execute();
```

full function code

```
protected function executeInsert(Insert $insert)
    {
        $insertState = $insert->getRawState();
        if ($insertState['table'] != $this->table) {
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException('The table name of the provided Insert object must match that of the table');
        }

        // apply preInsert features
        $this->featureSet->apply('preInsert', array($insert));

        $statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($insert);
        $result = $statement->execute();

        $this->lastInsertValue = $this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue();

        // apply postInsert features
        $this->featureSet->apply('postInsert', array($statement, $result));

        return $result->getAffectedRows();
    }
```

After this line code not working means its showing above error

Comment: Have you looked at your logs? If you don't have access to them, enable error reporting to catch and display.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner

I checked logs and also tried try and catch but only showing same error

Comment: The Exception at the start of the file is what I've got on that line (290) in that file, presuming you and me have the same version. What are you finding to be unclear about that message? (message in case of edits: `'The table name of the provided Insert object must match that of the table'`)

Comment: yes its very unclear message,

its resolved now,
 issue due to Smtp mail before saving into database and showing error at sql part

thanks